# What do the YouTube movie ratings mean?

Tags: youtube

While perusing in the "new" movie section, I noticed some movies have "ratings." eg: L, N, S, V, D.

What do those letters mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The YouTube Content ratings are based on **L**anguage, **N**udity, **S**exual Situations, **V**iolence and **D**rug Use

#### Language

- **L** : *Strong Language*

  Content rated **L** may contain some expletives and profanity; however such words should be infrequent and not used in a sexual context. Content with expletives and profanity that have been bleeped should be rated **L** as well. An **L** may also indicate suggestive dialog, sexual innuendo, or other discussion of adult themes. Other L-rated speech may include the expression of strong views and opinions that viewers are likely to find offensive, disrespectful, or otherwise controversial.
- **L+** : *Explicit Language*

  Content rated **L+** may contain persistent use of expletives and profanity. It may also include coarse and vulgar dialogue that is sexually explicit.
- *No Strong Language*

  Content rated **No strong language** should be free of any strong, coarse, or other potentially offensive language. Even mild cursing such as "hell" and "damn" or words that are bleeped should be rated as **L** or **L+**.

#### Nudity

- **N** : *Minimal covering*

  Content rated **N** may contain individuals who are minimally clothed (e.g., low cut tops, underwear or revealing bathing suits). Content rated **N** should not contain any fleeting or prolonged nudity, including exposed buttocks, genitalia, or areola.
- **N+** : *Some nudity*

  Content rated **N+** may include content featuring exposed buttocks or partially nude breasts. Content rated **N+** may also contain full nudity where the context is appropriately educational, documentary or artistic.

  *Note:* Some shows and movies may contain **N+** content that would generally not be accepted on the site. Videos originating from the YouTube user community must abide by the [YouTube Community Guidelines](http://www.youtube.com/t/community_guidelines?hl=en_US) and may not be permitted to include such content.
- *No Nudity*

  Content rated **No nudity** should be free of nudity or partial nudity of any kind.

#### Sexual Situations

- **S** : *Mild sexual situations*

  Content rated **S** may contain mild sexual activity or themes. This includes implied sex acts, light or comedic fetish references or behavior, or the presence of mild sexual situations or discussion.
- **S+** : *Explicit sexual situations*

  Content rated **S+** may contain explicit sexual content. This may include dramatized sex acts, explicit sexual situations or discussion.

  *Note:* Some shows and movies may contain S+ content not otherwise permitted on the site. Videos originating from the YouTube user community must abide by the [YouTube Community Guidelines](http://www.youtube.com/t/community_guidelines) and are not permitted to include such content.
- *No sexual situations*

  Content rated **No sexual situations** should be free of any sexual conduct or themes. Brief displays of affection, such as a kiss or hug are excepted.

#### Violence

- **V** : *Mildly violent or disturbing*

  Content rated **V** may contain mild, comedic violence, fantasy violence, or isolated incidents of realistic violence. However, any violence depicted should not be gory, pervasive, or sexual in nature. Similarly, V-rated content may contain a small amount of other imagery or situations that are disturbing or repulsive to sensitive viewers (such as real or dramatized medical footage, or depictions of disgusting or scary content in a horror or fantasy context).
- **V+** : *Strongly violent or disturbing*

  Content rated **V+** may contain violence that is persistent, intense, and graphic. Content rated **V+** may include pervasive imagery or situations that are disturbing or repulsive to the average viewer. This may also include animated content, if it features realistic depictions of extreme violence or other extremely disturbing or repulsive imagery.
- *No violence or disturbing content*

  Content rated **No violence or disturbing content** should be free of violence, injury, or other imagery that may be considered gory, disturbing, or repulsive to sensitive viewers.

#### Drug Use

- **V** : *Mild drug use*

  Content rated **D** may contain mild drug use, including excessive or persistent consumption of alcohol or tobacco. It also may include incidental or comedic use of drugs such as marijuana, sativa, hallucinogens or prescription pharmaceuticals. Implied, non-graphic use of other drugs, such as heroin, may be rated **D** as well.
- **V+** : *Drug use*

  Content rated **D+** may contain graphic, fictional depictions of drug abuse and display of drug paraphernalia. Content rated **D+** may also contain actual depictions of drug abuse where the context is appropriately educational, documentary or scientific.

  Note: Some shows and movies may contain **D+** content not otherwise permitted on the site. Videos originating from the YouTube user community must abide by the [YouTube Community Guidelines](http://www.youtube.com/t/community_guidelines) and are not permitted to include such content.
- *No Drug abuse*

  Content rated **No drug abuse** should be free of any drug abuse. However, fleeting and moderate consumption of alcohol or tobacco by adults as well as responsible use of medications may appear.

Answer (score 2):

When you do reach the movie page (which for some <s>countries</s> movies requires paying), expand the movie information box and click on the "What does that mean" you finally get the [content ratings help page on Youtube](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146399). In short:

- **L** for language (expletives, profanities, sexual innuendo, even if bleeped out, or even potentially offensive/disrespectful strong views on controversial topics)
- **N** for nudity (scantily clad people)
- **S** for sexual situations (implied sexual acts, fetish references, mild sexual discussion)
- **V** for violence (mild, comedic, fantasy or realistic but isolated; in no cases gory, sexual or pervasive)
- **D** for drugs (persistently, tobacco, alcohol; occasionally, stronger stuff)

All ratings come with a + version (L+, N+, S+, V+, D+) if there's more of each theme than described above. (N+, D+ and S+ content is generally not accepted on Youtube either.)

Answer (score 1):

An additional rating of F means the clip contains flashing lights which could be problematic for people with seizure disorders.

From [Google Support](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/146399?hl=en):

> Flashing lights (F):
>
> - None: No flashing light or other strobing content that could affect those with photosensitive epilepsy.
> - Flashing or strobing light: Contains flashing light or other strobing content that could affect those with photosensitive epilepsy.